# Div located on the corner of another div

Tags: html, css

With code lik this I can put div2 in the bottom right corner of a div1,
html:

```
        <div id="div1">
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text2</p>
            <div id="div2">div2</div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
        #div1 {
            background: green;
            width: 100px;
            border: 2px solid green;
            position: relative;
        }

        #div2 {
            background: red;
            width: 50px;
            border: 2px solid red;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }
```

but how can I put the div2 on a corner like this:
[image]

Comment: Try removing position absolute

Comment: I have a simple and easy solution, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple solution to this question. First, you remove the `position: absolute` from `#div2`.

Then, you give a fixed `height` of `95px` on `#div1`.

After, you simply put `margin-left` set to `70px` on `#div2`.

Here is a working snippet.

```css
#div1 {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 95px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

#div2 {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text2</p>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does the 70px come from? My div1 is 30px by 34px and div2 is 16px by 16px. What number should I use for margin-left on my div2?

Answer (score 1):

```
 #div2 {
      bottom: -25px;
      right: -25px;
 }
```

25px corresponding to the width of your red square / 2.

Answer (score 1):

here it is :

```
    <div id="div1">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <div id="div2">div2</div>
    </div>  


   #div1 {
        background: green;
        width: 100px;
        border: 2px solid green;
        position: relative;
    }

    #div2 {
        background: red;
        width: 50px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;

        z-index: 2;
        left:60%;
    }
```